# Static поля вместо Intent или Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, static

Когда я передаю не примитив, а свой придуманный объект между activity или в каком нибудь Frame, почему бы мне не использовать запись и извлечение через статичное поле своего класса? 
Чем это хуже тех страшных конструкций, которые предполагаются в моем случае с интентами и Bundle?